# How to make 3 tables column in one column line?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have the following 3 tables, but as you can see the columns are not in one line, i did the following CSS but still i get the same output. so how can i make the columns of different tables in one line and arrange them?

my HTML/CSS codes:

```css
.calculated-value td {
  border: none;
}

div#time-div {
  margin-left: -4%;
  margin-right: -4%;
}

table.calculated-value tr td:first-child {
  border: none;
}

table.calculated-value tbody tr td:first-child h4 {
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

table.calculated-value tbody tr td:not(:first-child) {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.calculated-value-title {
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-weight: 600 !important;
}

tr#time-row td {
  background-color: #22356d;
  width: 30px !important;
  text-align: left;
}

tr#time-row td:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

tr#time-row td:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9 offset-md-1" id="report-tables-container">
    <h4 class="text-center text-white font-weigh-bold calculated-value-title">FAIR MARKET VALUE </h4>
    <table class="table table-center text-white text-center calculated-value">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h4>INSTALLED</h4>
          </td>
          <td> 100
            <br>$149,350</td>
          <td> 100%
            <br>$149,350</td>
          <td> 100%
            <br>$149,350</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h4>EXCHANGE</h4>
          </td>
          <td> 100
            <br>$149,350</td>
          <td> 100%
            <br>$149,350</td>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div id="time-div">
      <table class="table table-center  text-white text-center text-strong font-weight-bold calculated-value">
        <tbody>
          <tr id="time-row">
            <td>TIME (MONTHS)</td>
            <td> 0</td>
            <td> 12</td>
            <td> 24</td>

          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>
    <h4 class="text-center text-white font-weight-bold calculated-value-title">LIQUIDATION VALUE</h4>
    <table class="table table-left text-white text-center calculated-value">
      <tbody>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <h4>ORDERLY</h4>
          </td>
          <td> 100
            <br>$149,350</td>
          <td> 100%
            <br>$149,350</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h4>FORCED</h4>
          </td>
          <td> 100
            <br>$149,350</td>
          <td> 100%
            <br>$149,350</td>
          <td> 100%
            <br>$149,350</td>

        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check this picture.

[image]

Comment: Can you not just put them in a single table? Otherwise just set the width of the td:first-child

Comment: Why do you want to have 3 separate tables instead of just 1?

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle for getting better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Tables are not connected to each other in any way and will not align to each other automatically. CSS is a way to go to make them look consistent. This is approx way of doing it.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
}

td {
  width: 9%;
}

td:first-child {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Very long long long long long name</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>80</td>
        <td>80</td>
        <td>80</td>
        <td>80</td>
        <td>80</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>80</td>
        <td>80</td>
        <td>80</td>
        <td>80</td>
        <td>80</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>80</td>
        <td>80</td>
        <td>80</td>
        <td>80</td>
        <td>80</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks, But since i have to use the middle table inside of div because of some design issues, your suggestion cant really help! any other way?